# Android: is there a mechanism for one user to purchase an app for other users?

Tags: android

Say a company would like to purchase my app for each of its employees. Each employee has their own Google account.  But, in order for the company to pay for the app for their account, they need to log in with their account, and have access to the company's credit card information.  Is there any convenient way for a company to purchase an app for its employees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to implement a licencing system.  Have the market version of the app require a key be entered before it starts working.  You'll need a backend system to manage the creation and usage of these keys that will also provision the app on the phones.

There may be a better way but I've never heard of a "gifting" mechanism for the Android market.

Comment: I wouldn't want to have the market version require a key, because I would want regular users to purchase through the market.  But I could make another build which requires a key.  However, if I made this special build and then made it available from my website (to prevent the confusion of having to different versions on the market), will it show as an "off market" app?  Is there anyway to allow it to be installed without users checking "allow unknown sources"?

Comment: If they get it from your website, they will have to enable side-loading apps.  Also, they will not have immediate access to any updates you make.  Your best bet is to have the 2 builds on the market - just make sure you are very clear with marking which is which (as Android market users do not like reading details like that).

Comment: Well, that isn't ideal, but makes sense.  Thanks for the advice.